# Put vanilla android on Samsung s5

Tags: rom-flashing, vanilla-android, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is it currently possible to put the default android on a Samsung S5 (Similar to the Google Play Edition of the S4)?

Comment: XDA developers is the place to go, and yes it is, there's TONS of AOSP and stock ROMs. Just ensure it's the EXACT device you have!